# How to create a pdf of each sheet in given spreadsheet in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a pdf of each sheet in a given spreadsheet, store it to google drive (or even google cloud platform), then log the URL of the pdf in the appropriate row of another spreadsheet based on an ID value found both on the spreadsheets, but I keep getting an error "TypeError: sheet.getBlob is not a function" Not sure what im doing wrong.

```
function createApplicationPDFsAndLinkToCustomerInfo() {
  var customerInfoSpreadsheetId = "CUSTOMER_INFO_SPREADSHEET_ID";
  var templateSpreadsheetId = "TEMPLATE_SPREADSHEET_ID";
  var folderId = "FOLDER_ID";
  var customerInfoSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(customerInfoSpreadsheetId).getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var customerInfoData = customerInfoSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var templateSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(templateSpreadsheetId);
  var templateSheets = templateSpreadsheet.getSheets();

  for (var i = 1; i < customerInfoData.length; i++) {
    var customerID = customerInfoData[i][10]; 

    for (var j = 0; j < templateSheets.length; j++) {
      var sheet = templateSheets[j];
      var sheetName = sheet.getName();
      var pdfBlob = sheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
      var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
      var pdfFile = folder.createFile(pdfBlob).setName(sheetName + "_" + customerID + ".pdf");
      var pdfUrl = pdfFile.getUrl();

      customerInfoSheet.getRange(i + 1, 26).setValue(pdfUrl); // Assuming you want to store the link in column Z (index 26)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Exact copy of [create a pdf of each sheet in a spreadsheet using app script](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/243048325). See [Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/1272824).